# How to fetch constants from a program?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, solana-client, client

So to fetch the current state of given account I'd do:

```
let acc = await program.account.<ACCOUNT_TYPE>.fetch(<ADDRESS>);
```

Programs can have hardcoded constants (which can be changed upon contract redeployment) such as:

```
 /**Price for an NFT item in USDC. */
 pub const NFT_PRICE: u64 = 6900000;
```

How would I be able to fetch this programatically from the client, without needing to refer to GitHub page where these constants would be readable (if opensourced)?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing constant values defined in your Solana program from a client application requires you to know these values beforehand since they are hardcoded into the program. These constants are part of the program's logic and are not stored on-chain, so they cannot be queried directly, like account data.